# Image does not set in imageview neither from bitmap nor from Uri?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, bitmap, android-camera

I am learning android. I am trying to take a picture from the camera and then save it in a specific folder "Myimages" and display the image in `ImageView`. When I capture the image from the camera the image is saved inthe myimage folder, but it is not getting displayed in `ImageView`. Ülease suggest me a solution.

1.layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"

        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/path"
        android:maxHeight="42dp"
        android:maxWidth="42dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 2;
File folder;
File imagefile;
TextView imagepath;

ImageView imageview;
Uri imageuri;
Intent intent;
String folderpath;
int ct = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imagepath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);

    createfolder();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {

        imagefile = getimagefile(folder);
        imagepath.setText(imagefile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imagefile));

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

    // imageview.setImageBitmap(bp);
    imageview.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imagefile));

}

public File getimagefile(File folder) {
    File mediafile;

    mediafile = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "img_"
            + ct + ".jpeg");
    ct++;

    return mediafile;
}

public File createfolder() {
    folder = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/Myimages");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    return folder;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you debug it and the file was found ?

Comment: yes i am getting this error while debugging .App crashes after capturing image.

Comment: Please post LogCat error.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the Bitmap into a BitmapDrawable, and then use SetImageDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

Data Intent find through onActivityResult there you can get image path and make File then make uri to setting imageUri in imageView.

```
String mTempImagePath = data.getData();
File file = new File(mTempImagePath .toString());
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
imageview.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(imagefile.getAbsolutePath()));

    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```